# mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nfs4

I need to mount an NFS4 share during boot so I added the following line to fstab:

```
10.250.35.12:/private/share /myshare nfs4 ro 0 0
```

The problem is that it does not get mounted during boot. Syslog says that access denied by server.
However, after logging in as root I can do a mount -a which works fine, it mounts the NFS share.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Please note that I do not have access to the server side.

Could you please advise how could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**(Moderator: please move this to comment. My reputation is too low).**

Try typing 'mount' after manually mounting the share and make sure the manual mount is going over NFS4.